# lisp - Can't load .lisp files on Windows

Tags: windows, common-lisp, clisp

I am using clisp 2.49 on Windows 7. I start the command window and navigate to the directory with the .lisp file. I then run clisp and try to load the file. I get error "there is no package with name C" on it. C in this case refers to drive C since the absolute path of the fill starts with C:/../../lispFile. I have also tried loading the file on Allegro CL but got the same error.

Below is a screen cap of the error message.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11mp1.jpg)

EDIT:
I have identified that the line of code that was causing the error message is:

```
(defparameter c:\\workdir\\aima\\ (truename "~/public_html/code/"); 
   "The root directory where the code is stored.")
```

I am not sure if the syntax is incorrect.

---

Solved: I figured out what I did wrong. I was given instructions to modify the lisp file but misunderstood it and replaced the wrong part of the line. Here is the corrected line of code.

```
(defparameter *aima-root* (truename "c:\\workdir\\aima\\"); 
   "The root directory where the code is stored.")
```

Comment: That looks more like your code tries to use a package that doesn't exist (`(C:something ...)`). Can you post the content of the file?

Comment: Next you would look at the backtrace  :bt  to see where it happens.

Comment: Please post a self-answer instead of putting "solved" in the title and your answer in your question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that one can also compute the directory during load time:

```
(defparameter *aima-root* 
  (when *load-pathname*
    (make-pathname :defaults *load-pathname*
                   :name nil
                   :type nil))
   "The root directory where the code is stored.")
```

`*load-pathname*` is a standard Common Lisp variable and will be bound during load time, to the pathname similar to the one used for the `load` function. Thus it points to the file being loaded. We then construct a new pathname, with the defaults filled from the *load pathname* and no name and no pathname type components.

Thus you can set the `*aima-root*` variable based on that computation and whenever you load the file, the correct directory will be computed.

There are two Common Lisp variables `*load-pathname*` and `*load-truename*` bound during load time. The latter is the real physical pathname of the file. Usually I prefer to use the `*load-pathname*`, which might not be related to the physical pathname structure. Here the code uses the function `truename` and thus it might be necessary to use the `*load-truename*`. Common Lisp implementations often record the location where functions and other things are defined, by storing the pathname. Finding the file later is sometimes easier with a pathname than using a truename - because it can have a device/machine independent indirection using *logical pathnames*.